# Getting Images and data from google sheet to wix as well as sending image from wix to cell

Tags: javascript, image, google-sheets, upload, velo

i want to receive images and some of the data from my google sheet to wix, but the only thing im receiving was the data but the column for images each row were empty. currently, my code is:

```
import { getValues, appendValues } from "@velo/google-sheets-integration-backend";
import { getSecret} from 'wix-secrets-backend';

//gets the log sheet data from google sheet
export const getValuesFromGoogleSheet = async(range)=>{
    const sheetID = await getSecret("sheetId");
    const result = await getValues(sheetID, range);
```

same thing goes to sending image like signatures, its is turning into a base64 URL

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is not supported by the Sheets API yet, and thus, it won't be supported by Velo either.

First let's look at the Velo Google Sheets integration [package](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/velo-package-readmes/google-sheets-integration). This has only 4 methods: `getValues()`, `appendValues()`, `updateValues()` and `clearValues()`. It's just focused on reading and writing **values** to the Sheet.

The problem with this is that images added via the menu under **Insert > Image > Insert image in cell** and **Insert > Image > Insert image over cells** are not considered "values". You can test this by creating a Sheet with a few images and running the [`spreadsheets.values.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) API on the cells where the images are located. The API will not return any results.

Now, this could mean that the image data could be stored in some other part of the Sheet object, but checking the [object definition](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet), it's nowhere to be found. If you try to retrieve a Sheet with [`spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) you also won't find it there. The Velo package uses the [googleapis](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/velo-package-readmes/google-sheets-integration#velo-package-readmes_google-sheets-integration_npm-packages) Node.JS package, which means that in the back end it uses the same Sheet API methods.

As an alternative, Google Apps Script does have the classes [CellImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/cell-image) and [OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image), which correspond to the image types in the insert menu I mentioned above. This does allow you to create the images, but to use [`getURL()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#geturl) on an `OverGridImage` the image has to have been [created in Apps Script](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122429709#comment6). And there appears to be a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215575446) about `getContentUrl()` not working for `CellImage objects. I got the same error and was not able to retrieve an image URL from these objects.

To support this, here's a [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129384672) with a feature request on Google's issue tracker about adding this to the REST API. And [here's](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215575446) another one, in addition to the links above.

Your best bet would be to use the [`=IMAGE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333) function in Sheets. This uses URLs so you would have to host the images somewhere else. You still cannot use the Velo package to retrieve them, though, since according to the docs above, the `getValues()` function only supports the parameters `(sheetId: String, range: String)`, and to retrieve a formula in text form you have to set the [`ValueRenderOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) parameter. You would still need to use the Node.js [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis), interface directly with the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) or use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).

##### References:

- [Velo docs](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/velo-package-readmes/google-sheets-integration)
- [Google Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129384672)
- [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest)

Comment: does =IMAGE() works with base64? or do i need to do something about that base64 before actually putting it in =IMAGE()

Comment: `IMAGE()` does not support base64. You'd have to convert it first and host it somewhere.